# XML Schema - validate elements of the same name

Tags: xml, xsd

I have the `<range>` element which may be defined alternatively (only one element in the node):

1. as a xs:string `<range>STH</range>`
2. or as a complex type:

> ```
> <range>
>    <value>0x00</value>
>    <value>0x01</value>
>    <value>0x02</value>
> </range>
> ```

How to validate it?
I tried do it like that:

```
> <xs:choice>
>     <xs:element name="range"  type="xs:string"/>
>     <xs:element name="range">
>         <xs:complexType>
>             <xs:sequence minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
>                 <xs:element name="value" type="xs:string" />
>             </xs:sequence>
>         </xs:complexType>
>     </xs:element> </xs:choice>
```

but still error occures

Thanks in advance

Comment: what is the error?

Answer (score 1):

An element can not have two types. The grammar would be ambiguous. Even two simple types are invalid.

```
<xs:complexType>
    <xs:choice>
        <xs:element name="range" type="xs:integer"/>
        <xs:element name="range" type="xs:string"/>
    </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
```

For [details](https://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#cos-nonambig) see the standard.

> A content model must be formed such that during ·validation· of an element information item sequence, the particle component contained directly, indirectly or ·implicitly· therein with which to attempt to ·validate· each item in the sequence in turn can be uniquely determined without examining the content or attributes of that item, and without any information about the items in the remainder of the sequence.

If you have two "range" elements, one of type A and one of type B, they can only be distinguished, by analyzing the content. And this is not allowed.